# Magento 2 - What is the error in my observer - catalog_product_collection_load_before

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3.4

I want to get selected attributes in product listing page using observer,

app\code\Zero\DescBlock\registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(

    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,

    'Zero_DescBlock', __DIR__ );
```

app\code\Zero\DescBlock\etc\frontend\events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_collection_load_before">
         <observer name="ChangeDescBlock" instance="Zero\DescBlock\Observer\Data" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app\code\Zero\DescBlock\etc\module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Zero_DescBlock" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
    <!-- <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Catalog">
    </sequence> -->
</config>
```

app\code\Zero\DescBlock\Observer\Data.php

```
<?php

namespace Zero\DescBlock\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver as LayerResolver;

class Data implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category
     */
    protected $catalogLayer;

    /**
     * @param LayerResolver $layerResolver,
     */
    public function __construct(
        LayerResolver $layerResolver
    ) {
        $this->catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Get selected filters
        $layer         = $this->catalogLayer;
        $activeFilters = $layer->getState()->getFilters();
        $this->logger->info(print_r( $activeFilters, true));

    }
}
```

The logger not return selected attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your php class. Logger is not defined.

```
<?php

namespace Zero\DescBlock\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver as LayerResolver;

class Data implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category
     */
    protected $catalogLayer;

    /**
     * @param LayerResolver $layerResolver,
     */
    public function __construct(
        LayerResolver $layerResolver
    ) {
        $this->catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Get selected filters
        $layer         = $this->catalogLayer;
        $activeFilters = $layer->getState()->getFilters();
        $this->logger->info(print_r( $activeFilters, true));

    }
}
```

This **SHOULD** work but I have not tested.

```
<?php

namespace Zero\DescBlock\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver as LayerResolver;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class Data implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category
     */
    protected $catalogLayer;
    
    /**
     * @var \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    /**
     * @param LayerResolver $layerResolver,
     */
    public function __construct(
        LayerResolver $layerResolver,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        // Get selected filters
        $layer         = $this->catalogLayer;
        $activeFilters = $layer->getState()->getFilters();
        $this->logger->info(print_r( $activeFilters, true));

    }
}
```

But why not use xdebug. print_r + log is alot of work to see the output.

Comment: I am selected one attribute in product listing page, may i know why its not available in syste.log file?

Comment: If we add " $this->logger->info(print_r( $activeFilters, true));
" the log should be paste in system.log file right?

Comment: in your terminal, run `tail -f var/log/*.log` and then run your request. Whichever log its printing in, it will show in the terminal.

Comment: I am using windows, can't able to run your command.

Comment: It could be exception.log or debug.log. You can also run `ls -altr var/log` and the log that was most recently edited will show at the bottom of the list

Comment: Still log not generated, how to test my observer working or not? any simple log should i use?

Comment: Sounds like its not working. Did you enable your module? `php bin/magento module:enable Zero_DescBlock`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119072/discussion-between-zus-and-shawn-abramson).

Comment: yes, its enabled

Comment: It can also be the specific event you are using. You are running your observer before collection load.

Comment: But regardless, your original posted code never added the logger into the observer so that would definitely prevent it from working

Comment: can you help me with this issue?

Comment: are you running `ls -altr var/log/` to see if a different log than you expected is being used?

Comment: also, i dont think youre watching the right event for this

Comment: the cmd ls -altr var/log/ not running, i am using windows.

Comment: what are you running magento on? directly on windows?

Comment: I am using xampp.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119072/discussion-between-zus-and-shawn-abramson

Comment: I have work based on attribute selection, so my first step i need to test my attribute selected or not,

Comment: As you know i am using the event : catalog_product_collection_load_before

Comment: You should try a plugin on the filter class

Comment: You should try a plugin on the filter class - Sorry, i am using observer right? what should i use instead?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119076/discussion-on-answer-by-shawn-abramson-m2-what-is-the-error-in-my-observer-c).